# Generating custom Axis interval with <p:lineChart>

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, charts

I am building a Web Application Response Monitoring.This will monitor the response time of various web applications.For visual representation of this responses I will use a line chart that will depict the performance of various websites in terms of responses.

For implementing this I am using PrimeFaces `<p:lineChart>`  component.I am using Prime Face 5.0.

**Details Of Graph:**
**X-axis:This will show the hours in 24 hours format,i.e x axis intervals will be like (0,1,2,3,4,5,..23)** since 24 hours in a day.I am starting with 0 so,max value will be 23.The gap between interval will be of "**1 hour**"

**Y Axis:** this will consist of **Response time in milliseconds**.The intervals will be in following format:(**0,5000,10000,15000,20000,25000,...,45000**).The gap between intervals will be "5000".Max value will be 45000 in Y axis.

Below is my managed bean class

```
 @ManagedBean(name = "chartView")
 @ViewScoped
 public class ChartView implements Serializable {


   private static final long serialVersionUID = 62250444917054924L;
   private LineChartModel lineChartModel;

   @PostConstruct
   public void init(){
       createChart();
   }


   private void createChart(){
      lineChartModel=new LineChartModel();
      lineChartModel.addSeries(initLineChart());
      Axis xAxis=lineChartModel.getAxis(AxisType.X);
      Axis yAxis=lineChartModel.getAxis(AxisType.Y);
      xAxis.setTickInterval("1");
      yAxis.setTickInterval("5000");
    }


    private LineChartSeries initLineChart(){
      LineChartSeries chartSeries=new LineChartSeries();
      chartSeries.set(0, 10000);
      chartSeries.set(1, 15000);
      chartSeries.set(2, 18000);
      chartSeries.set(3, 12000);
      chartSeries.set(4, 13000);
      return chartSeries;
    }


    public LineChartModel getLineChartModel() {
       return lineChartModel;
    }


    public void setLineChartModel(LineChartModel lineChartModel) {
       this.lineChartModel = lineChartModel;
    }


    public static long getSerialversionuid() {
        return serialVersionUID;
    }
 }
```

here is my xhtml page

```
   <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <h:body>
       <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="lineChart_Div">
         <p:lineChart id="line" value="#{chartView.lineChartModel}" animate="true" maxX="23" minX="0"
           maxY="45000" minY="0" xaxisLabel="Hours" yaxisLabel="Response Time(ms)"/>
       </h:panelGroup>      
    </h:body>
  </ui:composition>
```

Now my problem is data is getting depicted in Graph but the intervals on X axis and Y axis are not been plotted in the way I have mentioned above.**In X-axis intervals appeared like(0.0000,1.6429,3.2857,4.9286,6.5714,... upto 23.0000)**,**but I want it to be in the pattern(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,,7,8,9,...,23)**

Likewise **in Y-axis intervals appeared like(0,11250,22500,33750,45000) but I want it to be in the format(0,5000,10000,15000,20000,...,45000).**

I think i need to customize the intervals for x axis and Y axis but not finding a proper way to do it.I read about **"extender"** attribute for customizing jqPlot in Prime Faces Chart.But unable to find a solution suitable to my case.

Can anyone provide a any suitable solution to this???
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.we need to use the "**extender**" attribute of `<p:lineChart>` tag as follows:

```
 <p:lineChart id="line" widgetVar="line" value="#{chartController.lineChartModel}" style="height:300px;" 
  animate="true"  extender="plotAxisInterval"/>
```

Now we need to define this "plotAxisInterval" function in my js file like this:

```
  function plotAxisInterval() {

      this.cfg.axes = {
          xaxis : {
                   min : 0,
                   max : 23,
                   tickInterval : 1,
                   tickOptions : {
                      formatString : '%d'
                   },
                   label : 'Hours',
                   labelRenderer : $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
                   labelOptions : {
                       fontFamily : 'Georgia, Serif',
                       fontSize : '12pt',
                       width : '10px'
                   }
                 },
           yaxis : {
                   min : 0,
                   max : 45000,
                   label : 'Response Time(ms)',
                   labelRenderer : $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
                   tickInterval : 5000,
                   tickOptions : {
                       formatString : '%d'
                   }
                }
            };
      }
```

finally include the js file inside the xhtml page like this

```
<h:head>
  <h:outputScript name="js/chart.js"/>
</h:head>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way to do this than using javascript...just use the Axis API.  For example, you can set the Tick Interval and Tick Format for the X Axis as below:

```
Axis xAxis = lineModel.getAxis(AxisType.X);
xAxis.setMin(1);
xAxis.setMax(30);
xAxis.setTickInterval("1");
xAxis.setTickFormat("%d");
```

Had to post as an answer due to not enough rep.